# If $F$ is representable, then $G$ is representable? If $G$ is representable, then is $F$ representable?

Tags: category-theory

Suppose $F : C \to Set$ is equivalent to $G: D \to Set$ in the sense that there
is an equivalence of categories $H : C \to D$ so that $GH$ and $F$ are naturally isomorphic. If $F$ is representable, then $G$ is representable? If $G$ is representable, then is $F$  representable?

Is the answer to either of these yes? If so, why? If not, why not?

Answer (score 8):

Write $K:\mathcal D\to\mathcal C$, for the "inverse" of $H$, i.e. $HK\cong Id_\mathcal D$ and $KH\cong Id_\mathcal C$.

Now we can note, unsurprisingly, that your questions are symmetric. If one holds, then both hold, because $G\cong GHK\cong FK$ follows from $GH\cong F$.

The question now is does $\mathcal D(D,H(-))\cong F$ imply that $F$ is representable. We have $$F\cong\mathcal D(D,H(-))\cong\mathcal D(HKD,H(-))\cong \mathcal C(KD,-)$$ The last is because $H$ is full and faithful.

If we rectify $H$ and $K$ to an [adjoint equivalence](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equivalence+of+categories#adjoint_equivalence), which we can always do, then we could go straight from $\mathcal D(D,H(-))\cong\mathcal C(KD,-)$ via the adjunction.

Comment: How would we argue without adjoints?

Comment: @ImagineTaylor What do you mean? The answer is actually doing it without relying on adjoint properties, it just mentions at the end that it is an even shorter proof if we rely on the rectification as adjoint equivalence.

Comment: Then why is $F\simeq D(D,H(-))$?

Comment: @ImagineTaylor If $G$ is representable, then by definition $G\cong\mathcal D(D,-)$ for some $D\in\mathsf{Ob}(\mathcal D)$. Therefore, $G(H(C)) = \mathcal D(D,H(C))$.