# If $F$ is representable, is $G$ representable, and the converse (Category Theory in Context, excercise 2.1 iii)

Tags: category-theory

I know that the same question was asked before, but I'm looking for some hints to get started on the question, rather than a full solution.

[If $F$ is representable, then $G$ is representable? If $G$ is representable, then is $F$ representable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3329362/if-f-is-representable-then-g-is-representable-if-g-is-representable-the)

The question is given as

[image]

My attempt:

I'm not sure how to begin this, but my attempt for ii) at least has been to note that since $F$ is naturally isomorphic to $C(c, -)$(the functor that sends every element of $c \in C$ to the Hom set $C(c,x)$) for some $c \in C$, $GH$ is also naturally isomorphic to $C(c,-)$, since natural isomorphism is transitive.

This implies that $GH$ is representable, which would seem to imply that $G$ is also representable, which I have not proved yet.

As for i), I'm not where to start, but my intuition is that it's false. But coming up with counter-example would be whole another issue.

Hints would be appreciated a lot, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent functors carrying representability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3377320/equivalent-functors-carrying-representability)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a hint for part ii). You have an object $c$ that represents $F$. To show that $G$ is representable, we should look for an object to represent it. Well, seeing as we have $c\in C$ and a functor $H:C \to D$, we have an object $H(c)\in D$. Perhaps this will represent $G$?

For part i), it might be useful to choose an inverse to $H$.